# JSDoc: What is a relationship between modules and namespaces

Tags: javascript, module, jsdoc, javascript-namespaces, jsdoc3

I faced a problem with understanding the purpose of namespaces and modules in a union. For example I have a class `Game.utils.Matrix`. I want to annotate `Game` as a namespace, `utils` as a module and `Matrix` as a class:

```
/**
 * @namespace Game
 */

/**
 * @module utils
 * @memberOf Game
 */

/**
 * Create a matrix
 * @constructor
 */
function Matrix(){}
```

It creates a documentation and the name path of the `Matrix` class is `Game.utils~ Matrix`, but if I follow the `Module` link its name path is `Module: utils` without the `Game` namespace prefix, and if I follow the `Game` link it does not contain the `utils` module link.

Moreover, I can't add another class to this module as This class is not shown in the `utils` module tab:

```
/**
 * Create Dictionary
 * @memberOf Game.utils
 * @constructor
 */
function Dictionary(){}
```

The question is: what is the correct way to document namespaces and modules and what is the use case for each of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I played with it a bit and I guess having modules in a namespaces is a bit tricky. What worked for me is to define a module `utils` and a namespace which references it. The module is called `utils` however, not `Game.utils` but in `Game` you can see a property which links to it.

```
/**
 * @namespace Game
 * @property {module:utils} utils
 */

/**
* @module utils
*/

/**
 * Create a matrix
 * @class
 */
function Matrix(){}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this a bit upside down. I was trying to document a namespace with a dot, but of course the object after the dot is a property of the parent namespace.