# How to create categories in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, lodash, jsdoc

### Background

I am documenting my own JS library, and I stumbled upon the lodash library ( https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4 ).

It's documentation has a sidebar with categories ( Array, Collection, ect ) and each one has documentation for the functions.

### Objective

I would like my documentation to have a similar structure using the latest JSDoc version.

### Problem

After investigating I couldn't find the jsdoc template used by lodash. I also couldn't find a similar feature nor how to replicate it using JSDOC.

### Questions

- Which JSDoc template is lodash documentation using?
- If the template is irrelevant, how can I have categories in my documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

After much research I concluded that adding a `@category` with jsdoc was impossible. In fact, many have tried before and failed:

- https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1136

The only way to somehow simulate this behavior is to use `@namespace`, but this solution is heavy in drawbacks and is limited in scope:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636783/1337392

Still, until such a feature is supported, this is what I am using.

Answer (score 5):

I've just released a new version of [better-docs](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs) `jsdoc` template and it supports @category tag. Just add it to your class/module/whatever and it will be namespaced in the sidebar.

https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs

Comment: wish this functionality was part of `jsdoc` by default!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share an answer that I finally had for once on stackoverflow. You can indeed add `@category` tags to your JSDoc, you just need to install this plugin via config file:

- https://github.com/ErnstHaagsman/jsdoc-plugins/blob/master/categories.md